# How some activity can be run in background.. no matter if any other activity is in foreground

Tags: android

How to run some activity without pausing it when some other activity comes in front(even home screen/desktop also)... The activity should execute in background no matter if other activity is executing in front..

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: can you post your reqiurement or else Igor Popov's answer is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking in to [**services**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html)?

> A Service is an application component that can perform long-running operations in the background and does not provide a user interface. Another application component can start a service and it will continue to run in the background even if the user switches to another application.